# dynamic dropdown list in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm using a dynamic dropdown list in my form 
I want to choose an area according to the chosen city
this is my view

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6 form-group{{ $errors->has('city') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="inputPassword4" style="padding-left:35em"><span style="color:red">*</span> city</label>
    <select id="city" name="city" class="form-control">
        <option ></option>
        @foreach($cities as $city)
         <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{$city->city}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <h6 class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('city') }}</h6>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6 form-group{{ $errors->has('area') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="inputEmail4" style="padding-left:50em">area</label>
    <select id="area" name="area" class="form-control">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <h6 class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('area') }}</h6>
    </div>
```

and this is the script

```
    $('#city').on('change',function(e){

            console.log(e);

        var city= e.target.value;

        $.get('/areas/'+ city, function (data){

              //console.log(data);
            $('#area').empty();

            $.each(data,function(i,area){

            $('#area').append('<option value ="'+area+'">'+area+'</option>');

            });
        });
    });
</script>e
```

the controller

```
 public function areas($id)
{

    $area = area::where('city_id', $id)->pluck("area","id");

    return Response::json($area);
}
```

routs :

```
Route::get('/areas/{id}', 'locationController@areas');
```

i used this code but it didn't work!

Comment: var city= e.target.value; alert this means debug this whats the value you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `return Response::json($area);` use `return response()->json($cities);`

Your controller will be:

```
public function areas($id)
{

    $area = area::where('city_id', $id)->pluck("area","id");

    return response()->json($area);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your route from web.php. And what are you getting as a response? Can you check from your **Inspect** -> **Network** (for chrome)

Comment: i added the route to the question code .
what should i see as a response in the network?

Comment: when I call the rout areas/id in the URL 
it returns the areas perfectly.

Comment: if you uncomment `console.log(data);` on your script. What are you getting?

Comment: web.php: `Route::get('/areas/{id?}', 'locationController@areas')->name('areas');`  Script: `$.get('{{route('areas')}}/'+ city, function (data){`